# To whom do emails get sent via the Wordpress comments form?

Tags: comments, comment-form

I am working on a Wordpress 3.9.1 site, specifically the comments form.

I have a copy of the site on my server and I want to test the form in the following three ways:

- Adding a new comment
- Replying to a comment
- Replying to a reply of a comment

To do so, I want to be careful not to send many emails out to the site owner, and I want to be **very** careful not to send any out any email to site users.

I see under site > admin that there are options to "E-mail me whenever":

- Anyone posts a comment
- A comment is held for moderation

These are both unchecked.  My question is whether there is anywhere else I should worry about emails being sent (eg if someone replies to a user, does the user get sent an email?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails are sent to site admin`(settings->general E-mail Address)` when you check the email me option . No need to worry if you un-check that assuming you are not using any plugins that overrides.

Comment: Thanks.  What about the potential for emails being sent to users?  Do they get an email when someone replies to their comment?

Comment: no emails will be sent to users unless they subscribe to comments on the post(if comment form has option for subscribing)

Comment: Just using it out-of-the-box, so it doesn't seem to have a subscribe option.  Thanks for your help.